# watir-webdriver not finding or filling in text_field

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have a watir-webserver Ruby script I am developing, and I am having it first prompt the user for a username and password (with Ruby-Tk).

In any case, I can open the page with this code:

```
b = Watir::Browser.start 'https://connect.mypage.com/Home'
```

After that, I call the following:

```
t1=b.text_field(:id => 'ctl00_cphBody_txtUserName').when_present.set @entry1.textvariable
```

Nothing is filled in.

I have tried hard coding a name in for ctl00_cphBody_txtUsername, but that did not work either.

Using the Inspector in Firefox, the field is constructed as following:

```
<input name="ctl00$cphBody$txtUsername" id="ctl00_cphBody_txtUsername" class="firstFocus" maxlength="50" type="text">
```

The class of firstFocus is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.firstFocus').focus();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: a) Have you tried something like 'sleep 2' before loading the page? Maybe it will take a second or two for everything to load instead of filling everything when immediately you load the page. when_present didn't work for me in ajax-heavy sites. Also, before doing .set, try doing .fire_event('focus') on the element.

Comment: I put a Sleep(60) after b = Watir::Browser.start 'https://connect.mypage.com/Home'

Comment: Nothing is filled in and the only error/exception is when water-webdriver times out.

Comment: Have you tried sending it a javascript even like 'focus' more doing .set?

Comment: Is the element in a frame or iframe?

Comment: Here is the link; I don't see a frame or iFrame in the source(I searched the text for those two entities).As far as sending it a javascript event, I haven't tried that yet. https://www.blackboardconnect.com/signin/default.aspx

Comment: p.s. Now I am starstruck...I have been referring to Justin's page all day and just now put 2-and-2 together. I am confident then that we'll learn why this is not working. I tried firing the focus event, but so far have failed. I do not know (yet)how to invoke jquery from watir-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the locator is case-sensitive.

Notice that the id attribute value is "ctl00_cphBody_txtUsername" but the locator being used is "ctl00_cphBody_txtUserName". Due to the "N" not matching the "n", the element is never found, which is why the `when_present` times out.

Correcting the id in the locator will fix the issue:

```
t1=b.text_field(:id => 'ctl00_cphBody_txtUsername').when_present.set @entry1.textvariable
```

Answer (score 0):

If I start the browser and open the page like below, I have no problems locating those two text_field's:

```
browser =  Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://connect.mypage.com/Home'

#Then, the first item actually has a class, so I use that
t1=browser.text_field :class => 'firstFocus'
t1.set @entry1.textvariable
```